# Play video in fullscreen while click playbutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have video play play. I'm displaying the video in center of the view adjusting of CGRectMake. But when i click the play button i need to play video in full screen mode automatically without pressing maximize icon. Is it possible?

```
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"solar" ofType:@"mp4"]]];



     [[moviePlayerController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(172, 210, 680, 400)];

        [moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:NO];

        [moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];

        [[moviePlayerController backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];

           [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set MoviePlayer to FullScreen by below method

```
 mpviewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
[self presentModalViewController:mpviewController animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will embed your video to your iOS app:

1. Add MediaPlayer.framework
2. Add your video to the root of your project
3. In your .h file add the following

   `@property(nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer;` - Put this under `@interface ViewController :UIViewController;`
4. in your .m file, add the following

   `@synthesize moviePlayer;` -Put this under `@implementation ViewController`

   `NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your video name" ofType:@"mp4"];`

   `NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];`

   `moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];`

   `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];`

Answer (score -1):

> First try to use add observer pattern to know when movie player begins
>   to play at that time switch it to full screen mode. I am giving you
>   the link just check it. It may help you . In this link the observer
>   pattern is used for checking whether the player is enter on fullscreen
>   and in selector method what he wants to do he did. So u can also use
>   same methodology and instead of checking for fullscreen u should check
>   for play begin and on selector method set it to full screen..

[MPMoviePlayerController stops working in full screen mode // portrait orientation // iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246918/mpmovieplayercontroller-stops-working-in-full-screen-mode-portrait-orientatio)